# Converting to negative during select

Tags: sql-server-2008

Trying to figure out how to convert integer and decimal columns to negative within select statements.  Any help appreciated.

```
Begin
  Select 
    OrderInvoiceHeader.Invoice_int As [Invoice #],
    CustomerBillTo.BillToCustomerName As [Customer name],
    OrderInvoiceHeader.Invoice_date As [Invoice date],
    Salesmen.SalesmanName As [Salesman],
    (Select 
      Cast(Round(SUM(BaleInventory.NetWeight_dec), 0) As int)
      from dbo.BaleInventory

      Where dbo.BaleInventory.BaleNumber In     
       (Select OrderInvoiceBales.BaleNumber 
       from OrderInvoiceBales 
       Where OrderInvoiceBales.Invoice_int = OrderInvoiceHeader.Invoice_int)) 
       as [Lbs invoiced],
```

---

Here I need to convert `InvoiceAdjustment_dec` to negative if 
`OrderInvoiceHeader.InvoiceType = "3"`, same is true for other dollar values

---

```
OrderInvoiceHeader.InvoiceAdjustment_dec As [Adjustment $],
OrderInvoiceHeader.InvoiceFreight_dec As [Freight $],
OrderInvoiceHeader.InvoiceMerchandise_dec As [Merch $],
OrderInvoiceHeader.InvoiceTotal_dec As [Total $],
OrderInvoiceHeader.FreightPaid_dec As [Frt paid $]


From OrderInvoiceHeader

  Left Outer Join dbo.CustomerBillTo
  On OrderInvoiceHeader.BillToCustomer_int = CustomerBillTo.BillToCustomer_int

  Left Outer Join dbo.Salesmen
  On OrderInvoiceHeader.Salesman_int = Salesmen.Salesman_int

  Where 
    OrderInvoiceHeader.Invoice_date >= @From_date and
    OrderInvoiceHeader.Invoice_date <= @To_date

    Order By OrderInvoiceHeader.Invoice_int
End
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT ..... --all your other columns here
       CASE WHEN OrderInvoiceHeader.InvoiceType = '3' 
       THEN -1*InvoiceAdjustment_dec 
       ELSE InvoiceAdjustment_dec END AS InvoiceAdjustment_dec
```

Comment: I understand the case, works fine when Case is last in the Select, but if I interject the Case in the middle of the Select (to keep sequence for grid purposes) then syntax errors occur.

Comment: Sorry Lamak, my error in coding, all is fine.  Appreciate your help.